# String/char inputs with space

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am writing a small duty report cmd based program. While doing it I learned a lot but encountered one problem. When I try to write down notes with spaces between words I am just stuck in an endless loop. I used node to store the string data but it works for strings without space in it.

I have tried `cin.getline(Name, sizeof(Name));` which works perfectly for name input but not for the array of data

What I am trying to achieve that I got while loop where it reruns same lines until endshift variable is equal y to stop.

```
    while (end1 != "y")
{
    cout << "Field Treated: ";
    cin >> Field;
    cout << "Hospitalized: ";
    cin >> Hosp;

    SumF = SumF + Field;
    SumH = SumH + Hosp;

    cout << "Notes: " << endl;
    cin >> notez;
    note.createnode(notez);
    cout << "End shift: Y/N" << endl;
    cin >> end1;

}
```

And when it comes to "Notes" I am unable to input data with multiple words/space

UPDATE:

I understand that I need to read data in the loop if it is in an array. I need to input "notes" multiple times to array with spaces in it. For example, a note could be 1. There was a long day today so I took a nap. 2. Nothing. I don't know if that makes sense

My variables:

```
    list note;

int SumF = 0, SumH = 0, Field, Hosp, n = 1;
string end1;
char Name[100];
string notez;

//Time

int StartShiftHH, StartShiftMM;
int EndShiftHH, EndShiftMM;

char ch;
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. We don't know what your variables' types are and what input you want to type. If I understand correctly, you want to read whole array in one line? That's not possible, you have to use a loop and read data in that loop.

Comment: I understand that I need to read data in the loop if it is in an array. I need to input "notes" multiple times to array with spaces in it. For example, a note could be: 1. There was a long day today so I took a nap. 2. Nothing. I don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: Take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline . Read the notes carefully, as mixing `std::getline` with `operator>>` might not work as you would expect.

Comment: The first thing you need to understand is that if you don't post a [**minimal reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code it's very hard to help you.

Comment: @SimonKraemer Notes line automatically will be skipped for some reason. I can't input if I try doing this.

Comment: @anastaciu all the input is being done in that while. Here is a link to github where entire project is placed. https://github.com/DoIReallyNeedIt/DutyReport

Comment: @LukasSliuzas, what I'm telling you, and the link provided explains, is that the code you post must be a reproducible example, preferably one that you copy/paste to a compiler and reproduce the problem you describe. For example, we dont know what list is. The repository has this but you must post it here. Again, the links I provide are a must read and takes 2 minutes. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is also recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Data with whitespaces wasn't working so I found `getline(cin >> ws, notez);` and everything now works. Data is placed correctly into the array.

Tried `getline (cin, notez)` which didn't ignored white spaces so I added `ws`